# Does making DataFrame smaller makes it faster?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read an article (https://www.ritchieng.com/pandas-making-dataframe-smaller-faster/) which mentions that it makes the DataFrame faster by making it smaller (by converting data type).

Is there any association between smaller (memory usage) and faster (cpu time)?

Let's say I have a DataFrame column of **int64**. If we convert it to **int8**, will the operation on the column be faster?  e.g. assuming that the operation is `d[col] = d[col] + 1`

Comment: what does "I don't see the association between smaller and faster" mean?

Comment: Please share any measurements that you have made.

Comment: @MadPhysicist sorry for the confusion. I've changed my wording to ... "Is there any association between smaller and faster?"

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have actually done one experiment. I create a for loop of 100,000 times calling a function. the function is simply doing d[col] = d[col]+1. I observed that if the datatype is int16, it is faster than int64

Comment: Please show your results

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks for the suggestion. My experiment is like what MaxU answers below. The result is that speed performance of int8 operation is better than that of int64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not to test it?

## int64 dtype

```
In [29]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(10**7, 10), dtype="int64"))

In [30]: df.dtypes
Out[30]:
0    int64
1    int64
2    int64
3    int64
4    int64
5    int64
6    int64
7    int64
8    int64
9    int64
dtype: object
```

memory usage (in MiB):

```
In [31]: df.memory_usage().sum() / 1024**2
Out[31]: 762.9395294189453
```

timings:

```
In [32]: %timeit df.agg(["min","max","mean"])
4.68 s ± 84.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [33]: %timeit df+1
818 ms ± 26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

## int8 dtype

```
In [34]: df2 = df.astype("int8")

In [35]: df2.dtypes
Out[35]:
0    int8
1    int8
2    int8
3    int8
4    int8
5    int8
6    int8
7    int8
8    int8
9    int8
dtype: object
```

memory usage (in MiB):

```
In [38]: df2.memory_usage().sum() / 1024**2
Out[38]: 95.36750793457031
```

timings:

```
In [36]: %timeit df2.agg(["min","max","mean"])
2.4 s ± 222 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [37]: %timeit df2+1
170 ms ± 10.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for your experiment! I did test is, but I am just curious why it is. int8 is faster than int64

Comment: @Denielll, [this might be interesting for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56518216/why-operations-with-dtype-np-int64-are-much-slower-compared-to-same-operations-w) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Changing the data type from int64 to int8 reduces the amount of bits required to store the data. This will drastically reduce your memory usage which will be very helpful when you have large data for intense computation. This increases the size of data that's possible with pandas before you get a memory error.

What will also increase performance is changing object-type columns to specific types since this allows type-optimisations.

Comment: @MaxU I know:) Was just wondering since I am certainly no pro at pandas so it would be nice to know if I said something wrong