# why operations with dtype np.int64 are much slower compared to same operations with np.int16?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Here is what i mean - `a` is a vector of 1.000.000 `np.int64` elements, `b` is a vector of 1.000.000 `np.int16` elements:

```
In [19]: a = np.random.randint(100, size=(10**6), dtype="int64")

In [20]: b = np.random.randint(100, size=(10**6), dtype="int16")
```

timings for different operations:

```
In [23]: %timeit a + 1
4.48 ms ± 253 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [24]: %timeit b + 1
1.37 ms ± 14.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [25]: %timeit a / 10
5.77 ms ± 31.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [26]: %timeit b / 10
6.09 ms ± 70.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [27]: %timeit a * 10
4.52 ms ± 198 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [28]: %timeit b * 10
1.52 ms ± 12.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

I can understand such a difference when Numpy will have to create a new temporary result in memory - the underlying C code will have to copy / fill much more data in memory.

But I can't understand such difference for assigning values in place like the following:

```
In [21]: %timeit a[::2] = 111
409 µs ± 19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [22]: %timeit b[::2] = 111
203 µs ± 112 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Do you have an idea why is it that slower even for those operations where Numpy doesn't have to create a copy / view?

Comment: Do you realize you have to write more data with the bigger dtype?

Comment: @user2357112, shame on me! Thank you! :-)

Comment: I don't know, but maybe those very simple and homogeneous operations are SIMD accelerated? In that case my understanding is int16 could literally do 4 times as many data points than int64 with each instruction.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: That would be likely; `numpy` is written for high performance number crunching, and simple vectorization would be an obvious optimization. That said, I wouldn't expect to see much impact from it unless the array fit in the processor cache; RAM is just too slow to feed the CPU fast enough to matter much.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for the insight. Any idea why when I compare `a+a` with `a.cumsum()`, `cumsum` is soo much slower? If it were I/O bound that shouldn't be the case, should it? Actually, I'm tempted to make that a proper question.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: If `a` is small enough to fit in cache, then vectorization would matter. If not, *shrug*, no obvious ideas. I'd suspect an implementation weakness, possibly related to `cumsum` having multiple operating modes that, if handled inline, rather than by divergent code paths, might slow things down a bit. You need a build with symbols and profiling to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading from memory costs something. Writing to memory costs something. You're reading four times as much data in, and writing four times as much data out, and the work is so much faster than the reads/writes to memory that it's effectively I/O bound. CPUs are just faster than memory (and the speed ratio has been getting more and more extreme over time); if you're doing memory-intensive work, smaller variables will go faster.